# Laravel Relationship problem for branch ,item and category

Tags: laravel

I have Branch, Item and Category model. Branch has many items and item belongs to a category. In Item model I have `branch_id` and `category_id`. How can I fetch Categories under this branch.

Comment: Post your model and controller code

Comment: @debasish nandi. Let me know if the answer worked for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Item's table as a pivot table and define a many to many relationship between Branch and Category. In Branch model define a relationship like this:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, "pivot_table_name", 'branch_id', 'category_id');
}
```

Put the name of Item's table name instead of "pivot_table_name".
Now you can get categories of a branch like this:

```
$categoriesOfBranch = Branch::find(1)->categories;
```

Comment: @debasishnandi If it works for you, please accept it as the answer so others can use it as well.